# Delphi, OleVariant as out parameter

Tags: delphi, dll, activex, ole

I have a third party ActiveX control that I import to my application.
One of the functions is imported as:

```
function GenerateMACClearIVSync(const KeyName: WideString;  
         out MacBytes: OleVariant): Integer;
```

What it does is to calculate certain 8 byte value and store it into "MacBytes" variable.
However, I am having problems with this function call, as it give me access violation.

This is the code I try:

```
var i: integer;
MacBytes: OleVariant;
begin
   MacBytes := VarArrayCreate([0, 7], varByte);
   i := GenerateMACClearIVSync('MMM22', MacBytes);
end;
```

I expect that MacBytes gets filled with 8 bytes of data, but instead I get Access Violation in Delphi.

On another end I see the ActiveX control creates the 8 byte data (by looking at the trace of the DLL).

Please, advise. Thanks.

Additional info:
I use Delphi XE5. Here is the imported function prototype:

```
GenerateMACClearIVSync(BSTR KeyName, VARIANT* MacBytes,long* pVal)
```

And this is how they call it:

```
VARIANT macResult; long length = GenerateMACClearIVSync(EncKey, &macResult)
```

When I import the ActiveX into Delphi I get the ..._TLB.pas file that contains this declaration:

```
IKXSDMCtrl = interface(IDispatch)
...
function GenerateMACClearIVSync(const KeyName: WideString; out MacBytes: OleVariant): Integer; safecall;
....
end;
```

And then, further below:

```
IKXSDMCtrlDisp = dispinterface(IDispatch)
...
function GenerateMACClearIVSync(const KeyName: WideString; out MacBytes: OleVariant): Integer; dispid 13;
....
end;
```

And further down:

```
TKXSDMCtrl = class(TOleControl)
...
function GenerateMACClearIVSync(const KeyName: WideString; out MacBytes: OleVariant): Integer;
...
end
```

Finally this:

```
function TKXSDMCtrl.GenerateMACSync(const KeyName: WideString; out MacBytes: OleVariant):   Integer;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.GenerateMACClearIVSync(KeyName,  MacBytes); 
end;
```

Comment: A bit more of information: I use Delphi XE5.
Here is the imported function prototype:

    GenerateMACClearIVSync(BSTR KeyName, VARIANT* MacBytes,long* pVal)

And this is how they call it:

    VARIANT macResult;
    long length =  GenerateMACClearIVSync(EncKey, &macResult);

Comment: Where's the calling convention? And what's with the three parameter version. I can't help feeling some of the details you present are wrong.

Comment: All I have is an ActiveX control to import, then Delphi generates the ..._TLB.pas file which contains also this:
  
    function GenerateMACSync(const KeyName: WideString; 
                             out MacBytes: OleVariant): Integer; safecall;

Comment: So is it safecall or not? These sort of details matter.

Comment: The "Three parameters" version is what C developer has sent to me, the last parameter is actually the return value of the function (I am not an expert on C++).
It is a safecall.

Comment: Why do you initialise the variant if it is an out parameter? Why are there important details in comments rather than the question? Why do the details in the comments not match those in the question?

Comment: Sorry if I don't follow the rules strictly, I am rather used to forum approach discussion.
I will move the important details into the question.
I don't see the details in comments being different than the question.

Comment: The difference is safecall or not safecall

Comment: Sorry, I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Got it partially resolved: it crashes only if I run the app in debug mode. If I run the EXE by double clicking it then the application runs properly without any errors.
I have no idea what causes the problem, but I will move on with the project as this was a big stopper. Maybe some Delphi guru can give more explanation.

Comment: I think this is NOT the problem. I think you should be creating a VarArray of varVariant  element type.